# Basic information or texts required about modelling k bernoulli trials

Tags: spss, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, references, bernoulli-distribution

I have been presented with a dataset comprised of individuals and the number of teeth they have had extracted. The maximum is 32, and almost half of the data are zeros. I have been asked to suggest an appropriate multivariate model for these data.

I originally thought this would be a negative binomial distribution however it was pointed out to me that the count of extractions could represent a series of Bernoulli trials.

I have not modelled events/trials data before and I cannot seem to find any texts that explain this (I might be using incorrect keywords), and assist me to interpret the results correctly.

Can someone point me to some texts that explain this? I would be happy to read any texts relating to SAS, Stata, SPSS or R however would prefer an applied text and not an overly theoretical text.

Comment: A Bernoulli trial *follows* the binomial distribution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial

Comment: Thanks, I understand the distribution, I'm looking for assistance in modelling the data when it consists of k trials per unit. I am also interested in determining whether in fact the dependent variable does represent a series of bernoulli trials or whether it could be considered to be a count variable.

Comment: $k$ independent trials per unit? What is a unit in your example?

Comment: In my question I mentioned that the data I have are the number of teeth that people have extracted, so units = person, trials = 28 (i.e. total number of teeth) and success = extracted.
I need to know whether a) it is appropriate to use a generalised linear binomial regression to model these data and b) whether there are some texts specifically to use with SPSS.

Comment: Are the subjects adults? Human adults have (or had ...) 32 teath, what is the number 28? total number of teeth extracted?

Comment: Yes, for some reason I wrote 28 (I think I was confused about the status of molars), I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is a fixed number of teeth per person, so number of extracted teeth is a bounded variable, and maybe a binomial distribution might be used, However, I doubt this. The probability of extraction is probably not a constant for each teeth, and the total number of events then do **not** have a binomial distribution (*). I would also guess that the number of teeth extracted is nowhere near the theoretical maximum, so the bounded nature of the variable can be forgotten about! I would start out with a negative binomial distribution , better than poisson because of the varying probabilities of extraction.  To say much more than this you would need to say more about your data and about what questions you want to ask them!

(*) the distribution of a sum of independent Bernoulli trials with different $p_i$'s is called the poisson-binomial distribution. If you have enough data to estimate the different $p_i$'s, that could be a possibility. There is even an R package `poibin`.

Comment: Thankyou that is extremely helpful. I posted this quite a while ago and ended up using a negative binomial model, so it's interesting to hear another person who suggests the same thing. I agree with you that the probability of extraction is not a constant. This is something that I disagreed with my supervisor about however my modelling showed that the negative binomial model had a better fit than modelling a binary distribution (bernoulli trials). I still have an issue modelling the large number of zeros but the project is now on the back burner.

Comment: I have no idea why one would go for negative binomial (=overdispersed Poisson) as opposed to an overdispersed binomial (e.g. beta-binomial or some other version with a random subject effect), these models make a lot of sense, because not all people have the same probability and once one tooth comes out that probably ups the probability of further ones. Or some other variant of the Bernoulli/binomial (as you say it should be possible to account for different probabilities for different teeth).

Comment: Yes, you are probably right that my answer needs some reworking/rethinking ... thanks!